# Flask-Migrate/Alembic not detecting models using base class and multi-file structure

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, alembic, flask-migrate

This question has been asked a million times but none of the solutions seem to be working for me. I should note I've dealt with tangential issues quite often in other projects

Currently I'm using flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate, and postgresql.

File structure:

```
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── routes.py
│   │   └── users.py
│   ├── models
│   │   ├── annotations.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── mixins.py
│   │   └── users.py
├── config.py
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── icc2.py           <-- the app.py
├── migrations
```

`app/__init__.py`

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_cors import CORS
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from flask_migrate import Migrate

from config import Config

db = SQLAlchemy()
migrate = Migrate()

def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_class)

    db.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)

    app.es = Elasticsearch([app.config['ELASTICSEARCH_URL']]) \
        if app.config['ELASTICSEARCH_URL'] else None

    from app.main import bp as main_bp
    app.register_blueprint(main_bp, url_prefix='/_api')

    CORS(app, resources={r"/_api/*": {"origins": "*"}})
    return app
```

`icc2.py`

```
from app import create_app, db
from app.models import classes

app = create_app()

@app.shell_context_processor
def make_shell_context():
    print(db)
    return dict(db=db, **classes)
```

`app/models/mixins.py`

```
from app import db

from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declared_attr, as_declarative

@as_declarative()
class Base(db.Model):
    """This Base class does nothing. It is here in case I need to expand
    implement something later. I feel like it's a good early practice.

    Attributes
    ----------
    id : int
        The basic primary key id number of any class.

    Notes
    -----
    The __tablename__ is automatically set to the class name lower-cased.
    There's no need to mess around with underscores, that just confuses the
    issue and makes programmatically referencing the table more difficult.
    """
    __abstract__ = True
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls):
        return cls.__name__.lower()
```

`app/models/users.py` (`annotations.py` is similar)

```
import time

from datetime import datetime

from app import db
from app.models.mixins import Base

class User(Base):
    auth0id = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True)
    last_seen = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<User {self.displayname}>"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.displayname
```

`app/models/__init__.py`

```
import pkgutil
import os
import importlib
from .mixins import Base

pkg_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)

for (module_loader, name, ispkg) in pkgutil.iter_modules([pkg_dir]):
    importlib.import_module('.' + name, __package__)

classes = {cls.__name__: cls for cls in Base.__subclasses__()}
```

The iteration comes from a stackoverflow snippet so that I can get the models in a class to expose to the flask shell namespace.

I perhaps don't need to put these two classes in two separate files, but my last project ended up with 30 or so models and so organization demanded a bit of a split, so it's just a practice I've developed.

It is my understanding that alembic needs to see the metadata for the objects before it can generate the models, but at the point in `app/__init__.py` where migrate is instantiated the db does not have an engine yet. In fact, just to test how the engine is created, I added 3 print statements to `icc2.py` to print the db and see if it has an engine at that point, like so:

```
from app import create_app, db
from app.models import classes

app = create_app()
print(db)
@app.shell_context_processor
def make_shell_context():
    print(db)
    return dict(db=db, **classes)
print(db)
```

The only print call that didn't show `<SQLAlchemy engine=None>` was within the `make_shell_context()` function.

Finally, the output of flask migrate "Initial migration":

```
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.env] No changes in schema detected.
```

So how do I expose my metadata to flask migrate?

Comment: You have a bit of complexity layered up here, why not pair it back to a more standard configuration that you know works and then add the complexity back in bit by bit so you know what breaks it?

Comment: What was the state of your database at the time you ran `flask db migrate`?

Comment: @Miguel it was empty. At one point it had an alembic_version table added to it, and I dropped the table. If there's any specific tests you'd like me to conduct I'd be glad to. The repo is here: https://github.com/Anno-Wiki/icc2-backend I've actually just coded up my own initial commit for alembic but I'd still like to get migrate to work.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot really tell you what was the problem. There are two reasons why your migration can come up empty: 1. your database is already populated with the change (for example if you call db.create_all()) or 2. your models aren't being seen by SQLAlchemy. It has to be one of these two.

Comment: Thanks @Miguel. As I add features to the database I'll experiment with different possibilities. If I find the solution I'll post it here. I recall having trouble with naked alembic in similar ways and I solved by manually binding a Metadata object and importing it: https://github.com/malan88/ulaanbataar/blob/main/models.py I don't call db.create_all() anywhere in the project in question, so I'll spend some time tinkering. But I just want to say that I love your work, thank you for the Megatutorial, it's what taught me basic web application programming. Now I have a job in it.

Comment: @mas did you find anything? It's not ideal having to put all your models in one module for migrations to work.

Answer (score 3):

Importing * from the model modules inside alembic's `env.py` worked for me. Organizing the all the model modules and alongside the base module as * imports in a `__init__.py` and importing from that aggregation module in `env.py` also works.